# V-select button is not working in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

```
** Here I have v-select element it is not showing for the first element, Vuetify v-select element. Please help **   
    <template>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container align="center">
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="3" class="categ">
          <v-select
            cols="12"
            sm="3"
            class=""
            @change="setD"
            :items="categories"
            v-model="content.cat"
            outlined
            label="Select Category"
          ></v-select>
        </v-col>

        <v-col cols="12" sm="3" class="key">
          <v-combobox
            @change="setD"
            outlined
            label="Input Key"
            v-model="content.key"
          ></v-combobox>
        </v-col>

        <v-row
          class="childElements"
          v-for="(find, index) in content.data"
          :key="index"
        >
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6" class="key">
            <v-select
              @change="setD"
              :items="languages"
              v-model="find.lang"
              outlined
              label="Select Language"
            ></v-select>
          </v-col>

          <v-col xs4 class="childTwo">
            <v-combobox
              @change="setD"
              v-model="find.cont"
              outlined
              class=""
              label="Input Content"
            ></v-combobox>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-row>

      <v-row justify="center" class="buttonRow">
        <v-btn color="#96CEB4" @click="addFind" class="btnv"
          ><v-icon class="iconel">mdi-plus</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

** Here I have v-select element it is not showing for the first element, Vuetify v-select element. Is there any way to fix it please share your thoughts and answers I appreciate so much**
** Here I have v-select element it is not showing for the first element, Vuetify v-select element. Is there any way to fix it please share your thoughts and answers I appreciate so much**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use props which shouldn't be here.

```
<v-select
            @change="setD"
            :items="categories"
            v-model="content.cat"
            outlined
            label="Select Category"/>
```

Are you sure `categories` and `content` exist in `data()`?

Comment: aha now I get it thanks!